# Bacon.js `onError` not working

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, bacon.js

I have a function that calculates the aspect ratio of a height and a width input, and either throws an error, or returns an object with the aspect ratio.

```
var bestAR = dimensions.map(function(dim) {
    try {
       return findBestAR(dim.width, dim.height); 
    }
    catch (e) {
        return new Bacon.Error(e);
    }
});

bestAR.onError(function(e) {
    alert(e)
});
```

I can log the `new Bacon.Error` in my catch statement to the console and it contains the thrown error inside of `findBestAR`. However, it does not respond to the `onError` per Bacon. Maybe I'm not fully understanding how error handling in Bacon works.

Answer (score 1):

`.map` can only change value events into value events. To change a value event into an error event (or into a different number of events), you need to use `.flatMap` instead.